# Kops create /update cluster error doing DNS lookup for NS records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops

kops update cluster xyz.testexample.com

error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "xyz.testexample.com": lookup xyz.testexample.com on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host

Comment: add the `--dns private` flag. this should work

Comment: tried giving --dns private flag.. seems to give the same error :

kops create cluster --zones us-west-2a --ssh-public-key "/Users/username/.ssh/awsaccess_rsa.pub" --dns private ${NAME} 


Error:

Name: Invalid value: "xyzxyz": Cluster Name must be a fully-qualified DNS name (e.g. --name=mycluster.myzone.com)

Comment: Hey what is your clustername? You have to give a valid DNS name when creating it. Try giving it like this: `export NAME=clustername.k8s.local `

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "xyz.testexample.com": lookup xyz.testexample.com on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host
> ```

That error means Kops is unable to resolve the DNS name `xyz.testexample.com`.

DNS names in Kops are a critical path. Please check the resolving on your PC.  Managing the cluster will be impossible without a correct resolving.

What about creating a new cluster with private DNS (I see in comments that you tried to do it) - check that [how-to](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md), you need the path "Using Public/Private DNS (Kops 1.5+)".

Answer (score 0):

This error is as a result of missing dns nameserver. Kops cannot find the correct dns server on your local computer to reslove the subdomain.
Solution:

1. You should first go to route 53 hosted zone. Make sure your subdomain (kops.example.com) has the same dns nameservers as your domain (example.com). If not edit the nameservers of the domain by replacing the nameservers of the domain with that of the subdomain.
2. The next thing is to run nslookup of the all or one of the nameservers to resolve their IP addresses. e.g  nslookup ns-844.awsdns-41.net, results in 205.251.195.76.
3. Edit you /etc/resolv.conf and add a line nameserver 205.251.195.76.
4. Now run your kops command again and it will find the dns server and will be able to resolve your subdomain.